# Why is the error "Segmentation fault" here?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I tried to implement the recursive form of Selection sort. But error as "Segmentation fault " is being shown. Where is the error? What are the errors generally faced with recursive algorithms?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void ssort(int[],int,int);
void prints(int[],int);
void sorting(int[],int,int);

int a[]= {5,6,3,1,2,4};

int main()
{
    ssort(a,0,6);
    prints(a,6);
    return 0;
}

void ssort(int a[],int s,int e)
{
    int min=a[s];
    int ch,p,j;
    for(j=s+1; j<e; j++)
    {
        if(min>a[j])
        {
            min=a[j];
            ch=j;
        }
    }
    sorting(a,j,ch);
    if(s+1<e)
    {
        ssort(a,s+1,e);
    }
}


void prints(int a[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d",a[i]);
}

void sorting(int a[],int j,int ch)
{
    int p=a[j];
    a[j]=a[ch];
    a[ch]=p;
}
```

Comment: `int ch` --> `int ch=s`, `sorting(a,j,ch);` --> `sorting(a,s,ch);`

Comment: you are right. Thanks

Comment: One general error faced with recursive algorithms is stack overflow. This happens when your program runs over its allocated stack memory size. The stack (in program memory) is the place where function data lives (local vars, arguments, return address). Each function call on the stack is called a frame. If a recursive function generates too many frames on the stack then it will cause a stack overflow. You can try this will an infinite recursive function that no matter what always calls itself. Another possibility of stack overflow is defining an overly large local variable `double x[999999999]`

Comment: When facing segmentation fault errors I *highly* recommend using a debugger. You can use gdb or, if you are using an IDE, it probably has a graphical debugger built in. The debugger will tell you what line is causing the segmentation fault, the state of the the call stack, the values in your local variables at the time of the crash and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault is thrown when illegal memory is accessed. There is a possibility that "sorting(a,j,ch);" may get called even when the code may not have gone through the if block inside the prededing for-loop. In that case value of  "ch" may be unpredictable and then when u access a[ch] inside the sorting(..) function, it may be access some illegal memory which will cause segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

Comment by BLUEPIXY in the question pretty much solves the problem. Writing this to add why those changes are needed.

ISSUE 1: At each step of recursion you will store the minimum value in first index (for that level of reursion). To do this first you identify the index of the minimum value, which in your code you are stroing in `ch`. Then you swap the values in **first** index and the index with minimum value. That means your code  should be swapping the values in indexes `s` and `ch`. But, you are swapping the values in **last** index and the index with minimum value. So you need to make the below change:

```
/* sorting(a,j,ch); */   // ISSUE:   you are swapping with last index
sorting(a, s, ch);       // CORRECT: you are swapping with first index
```

ISSUE 2: If the condition `if(min>a[j])` is never true then `ch = j;` is never executed, and `ch` will have indeterminate value. And then when you call `sorting(a, s, ch);` your program will not have deterministic results, and it may even crash. So, you have to set `s` as the minimum index at the beggning, as:

```
/* int ch,p,j; */ 
int ch = s, p,j;    // Initialize ch with starting index
```

These changes should resolve you issue. However, one change you can make is, swap the values only if need:

```
/*sorting(a,j,ch);*/
if (ch != s)
    sorting(a, s, ch);
```

And finally, you may want to change the name of the function `sorting` to `swap`.